# Python subprocess timeout with time consuming tasks

Tags: linux, python, process, timeout

The following code allows running a subprocess with a timeout

```
p = subprocess.Popen([...])
while timeConsumedSoFar < timeoutLimit
    if proc.poll() is not None:
        doSomething
    else:
        time.sleep(2)
os.kill([...])
```

It works with regular linux commands. But some commands are time comsuming, such as 'shred'

```
'shred [OPTIONS] FILE [...] '
```

Shredding a logical volume could take more than 20 minutes. Is there a better way to deal with the issue?

Comment: this question is probably more suited for the Stack Overflow board. In any case, what do you want to do with the long process, to time it out or to let it continue? in the first case you can use the `timeout` command

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though subprocess handles interruptions of wait, so I couldn't use it.

Here is a (probably buggy) example which is the somewhat more traditional unix way to do it.
**NOTE** this does not produce any of the output that comes from stdout! In fact it produces no output at all.

It looks more than what it is because of all the comments.

Why you may consider this better is because we dont continually poll on the process. Instead, we tell the kernel to get back to us after a specified timeout *or* if the command completes. In either case the response will never be delayed more than a few microseconds from after the event, plus the code only ever needs to setup the first initial poll only.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def runwait(timeout, *args):
  from os import fork, execvp, waitpid, kill, dup2
  from signal import alarm, signal, SIGTERM, SIGALRM, SIG_DFL
  from errno import EINTR

  ## We dont do much in the alarm handler, we only care that we interrupted
  ## the wait() on the process.
  def onalarm(sig, frame):
    pass

  ## This is used for redirecting stdin/out/err to /dev/null
  devnull = open('/dev/null', 'r+')
  pid = fork()
  if not pid:
    ## The child process. Begin by redirecting all input and output.
    dup2(devnull.fileno(), 0)
    dup2(devnull.fileno(), 1)
    dup2(devnull.fileno(), 2)
    ## Probably not a great idea to pass this file descriptor to whatever we 
    ## end up executing.
    devnull.close()

    ## Overwrite child process with new execution context.
    execvp(args[0], args)
    ## If something failed (like command not found) exit 63. WARNING, because we
    ## redirected all output to /dev/null, you WILL NOT be informed the command was
    ## not found directly. Use the exit code to work that out.
    sys.exit(63)

  ## This is the parent process that initiated the fork.
  ## Arm a timer using timeout given by first parameter of function. This
  ## must be an int, not a float. I dont bother checking though cause I'm lazy.    
  signal(SIGALRM, onalarm)
  alarm(timeout)

  ## We wait on the pid, this call typically blocks forever.
  try:
    pid, rc = waitpid(pid, 0)
  except OSError as e:
    ## We will land here if the alarm triggered BEFORE the process completed!
    ## In this case, if we were interrupted to deal with the 
    ## signal handler its definitely an alarm. Otherwise
    ## a peripheral exception occurred (permissions for example) so just re-raise the exception.
    if e.errno == EINTR:
      ## We send a TERM signal to terminate the process and re-wait. This causes
      ## wait to (under normal conditions) come back immediately with the signal 
      ## we just killed it with which parse out further down.
      kill(pid, SIGTERM)
      pid, rc = waitpid(pid, 0)
    else:
      raise

  ## Waits status is a 16bit integer packing a 8bit signal and 8bit return code.
  ## Do some funky bitwise operations to separate the two..
  sig = rc & 0xff
  rc >>= 8
  ## Whatever happened above, always disable the alarm and signal handling.
  alarm(0)
  signal(SIGALRM, SIG_DFL)
  return sig, rc


if __name__ == "__main__":
  # An example when you time out
  print runwait(2, "sleep", "20")
  # An example on success
  print runwait(5, "sleep", "3")
  # More success, but demonstrating no output
  print runwait(5, "grep", "root", "/etc/passwd")
```

The function returns the signal number that killed the process (if any) and the return code of the executed program.